# Mutate Array of ActiveRecord objects and update in single transaction?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

What is the preferred way to update an entire array of ActiveRecord objects in a single transaction?  Assume there is a lot of processing in the loop.

```
@items = Item.all

@items.each do |i|
  i.name = somethingDynamic()      
end

#Commit @items to DB in single transaction
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply wrap the entire loop within a transaction:

```
@items = Item.all

ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
  @items.each do |i|
    i.name = somethingDynamic()
    i.save!      
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can start a transaction explicitly with `ActiveRecord::Base.transaction` like this:

```
Item.transaction do 
  @items.each do |i|
    i.name = something_dynamic() 
    i.save!
  end
end
```

This will run a bunch of `UPDATE items set name = x` statements within one transaction, and roll the transaction back on the first failure (since save! will throw an exception).

If you want to do something that doesn't require a bunch of update statements, you can do one update statement with raw sql like this:

```
 `@items.update_all("name = sql_func(name)")`
```